# Domain boundary Line going invisible in android plot graph

Tags: androidplot

While performing scrolling in android plot graph, domain boundary line is going invisible. How to fix this problem?

Comment: please show your research..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
mySimpleXYPlot.setDomainBoundaries(minval, 
                    maxval, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
```

where minval is the minimum value of the x axis.
and maxval is the max value on the x axis

Answer (score 0):

mSimpleXYPlot.setDomainBoundaries(minval, 
                    maxval, BoundaryMode.FIXED);